# How to join Clips in iMovie 10?

Tags: imovie

I know there was a function in the context menu to join video clips together, but I can't find it in the newer version of iMovie 10. Is it still available?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The joining clips function in iMovie 10 is located under the "Modify" menu.

YouTube video tutorial I made about how to join clips in iMovie 10: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-56DJblknE8

Answer (score 2):

There is still the Join Clips function here:

[image: join]