# iMovie "Join Clips" option greyed out

Tags: macos, imovie, video-editing

[Articles](http://www.informit.com/articles/article.aspx?p=2191412&seqNum=4), [Videos](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-56DJblknE8) and [similar posts](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/145124/how-to-join-clips-in-imovie-10) / [questions](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/184501/how-to-join-split-clips-back-in-imovie) all describe being able to join clips in iMovie using the *Join Clips* option in the *Modify* menu of iMovie (10.1.8) on macOS High Sierra.

### Yet, iMovie is unable to join two clips!

It seems to be a **common and recurring issue** to which I am seeking an answer once and for all.

**Background**
I have split a clip into 3 pieces and deleted the middle part. Now, having used <kbd>CMD</kbd> to select the two remaining pieces - highlighting them in yellow borders, I go up to the *Modify* menu to find that the *Join Clips* option is unavailable (greyed out).

**Question**
*Why am I not able to join the clips?* They are adjacent to one another, have no speed alteration (e.g. slow motion) and are both highlighted. *How do I join them?*

Comment: Did you figure that out? I'm facing same problem. Please help.

Comment: @Neha I have up after running into the same problem over and over again. Since then I've upgraded to Mojave but haven't tried it again. I ended up having to meticulously align the two but leave them as two separate clips.

Comment: I need an answer for this too.

Answer (score 8):

**Note:** Join clips option in iMovie cannot be used for joining two different imported video clips. It can only be used to join clips created by splitting an imported clip in iMovie.

So, essentially if you have two clips which are to be combined, click on the **Share icon** in the Top right corner, then click on the option **File** and export all the clips as a single video file. You may then re-import it into the project if required after the share is successful.

For a quick 2 min demo, watch this: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8Px_I5fvJbk

Comment: this software is unable to do the most basic edit feature as joining?